# 2D bounding box from PCL point-cloud

Tags: c++, bounding-box, pcl

I have a 3D PCL point cloud (XYZ, or type:  `pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>`) that has already been segmented and contains the object of interest.

I would like to find the 2D (X & Y, assuming Z is vertical) minimum bounding box that encompasses all the points, and then recover the 4 corners coordinates (X, Y) of this box.  The box doesn't have to be axis-aligned

What is the best way to do this using PCL?n

Comment: Not sure about the best approach, but first thing I would try is to just find X and Y extreme coordinates with `std::max_element` and `std::min_element` with custom comparator.